# Is it worth it to go to Mount Kenya for only one day?

Tags: africa, day-trips, mountain-climbing, kenya

Yesterday a friend told me that he will travel to Kenya and he's interested to go to Mount Kenya. He has only one or two days to go up this mountain, so he's wondering if there is something that justify to make a one day excursion. To clarify: he will be in a town very close to the mountain so the plan is to go up and down in the same day. If that's not possible, another option is to spend a night there. Worth it? Is there any company that organize this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that it depends if your friend want to get close to the mountain itself. It may be possible to get there overday from Nairobi to get som distant glimpses but it does not seem viable to go back and forth **and** do some climbing. This is also confirmed by a [thread at kenya-advisor.com](http://www.kenya-advisor.com/day-tour-from-nairobi-to-mount-kenya.html). There are several companies that arrange trips to the mount kenya and they should be easy to find with the appropriate google searches. I have only seen 3-day trips and longer when quickly browsing through some of the sites.

The mount is only some 150 kilometres from Nairobi but keep in mind that the road conditions may not be the best.

[image: mount kenya]
[photo by fredric.salein](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fredericsalein/5412789480/)

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to climb Mt. Kenya in one day. The usual route is 3days. 
Also cars are not allowed in the whole park. What you could do is driving to the entrance and than walk to one of the huts at, let's say 3500meters. 
So it is definitely a several day long trip... But it's worth it. I went to Mt. Kenya from Sandai Farm. They organizided everything. http://www.africanfootprints.de/en/safaris-kenya/several-day-long-safaris/